# reducer always fails and map succeeds

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning, reducers

I am running simple wordcount job on 1GB of text file . My cluster has 8 Datanodes and 1 namenode each has a storage capacity of 3GB.

When i run wordcount I can see map always succeeds and reducer is throwing an error and fails. Please find below error message.

```
14/10/05 15:42:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 31%
14/10/05 15:42:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201410051534_0002_m_000016_0, Status :  FAILED
FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
14/10/05 15:42:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201410051534_0002_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Task: attempt_201410051534_0002_r_000000_0 - The reduce copier failed
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local     directory for     file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201410051534_0002/attempt_201410051534_0002_r_000000_0/output/map_18.out
```

Could you please tell me how can i fix this problem ?

Thanks
Navaz

Comment: Have you set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb and 
mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor ? These control how much of the 
worker's memory is reserved for merges, and how much the output is 
split for merging. Could help.

Comment: Thank you SreeVeni. I havent set any of these properties ? What is the value i need to set for these two factors ?I have a storage of only 3GB in each of machines. And When shuffle starts it consumes all the disc space of one machine out of 8 and it throws above error.

Comment: After setting the mapred.local.dir to newly mounted disc it solved the problem
<name>mapred.local.dir</name>
<value>/mnt</value>
Thanks for the help :)